# Stripe testing: how to make cvc_check and address_zip_check set to true when using test token like tok_visa?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to test the Stripe API and want to use one of the test tokens like `tok_visa`.

(I can't really use the test cards like `4242424242424242` because my software is a middleware layer, and in normal operation it just passes a token through from client to server, and I'd prefer not to add logic for creating tokens just for the sake of testing.)

When I use `tok_visa` and retrieve the token data from Stripe, the `cvc_check` and `address_zip_check` are set to null.

The problem is on the test server I'm talking to, it requires that these be set to true. I also am unable to modify the test server to skip these checks.

The docs say that if you set the CVC or ZIP to any valid value then these checks should pass, but I don't see how to set the CVC number or address for `tok_visa` because it's already been tokenized.

Comment: There are other [testing services](https://www.testingpays.com/stripe/) where you can get back all the possible responses (or you can make your own one based on a production response)

Answer (score 4):

The test server is looking for a value (`true`) that is never going to come from a Stripe token.

The [possible values](https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/object#token_object-card-address_zip_check) for a token's `card.cvc_check` and `card.address_zip_check` are:

- pass
- fail
- unavailable
- unchecked

The test tokens will usually have a `null` value (but never `true` -- it's not a valid value). Some test tokens that Stripe provides will instead have `unchecked` if they are configured to fail when checked.

If you create a token in test mode, its value will be `unchecked` until you attach it to a customer or try to charge to it. At that point, it will become one of the other three values.